# CustomView not showing inside ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, android-canvas

New Android programmer here.

I'm trying to display an .png image as a bitmap on Android.  The only way I have been able to display the converted image at all is with a custom class that extends `View`.  However, my image is too large to be displayed entirely on the screen and I would like to be able to scroll with it.  But when I define a `ScrollView` and put the `Canvas` with the `Bitmap` into it, I get a blank screen.  I had no luck setting this up with the layout file, so it is all done in the Activity class.

This is where the Activity is created:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView(this);
    scroll.addView(new CustomView(this));
    setContentView(scroll);
}
```

And this is my CustomView class:

```
private class CustomView extends View{

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        Bitmap bitmapMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.resourceimage);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapMap,0,0,null);
        this.setWillNotDraw(false);
    }
}
```

And if I replace this line of code in my Activity: `setContentView(scroll)` 
with this line: `setContentView(new CustomView(this))`, I can see the image, albeit not the entire image.  So, is there a way to set this up in the layout files instead?  Or is there something I'm missing that I need to declare in the `ScrollView` class?

EDIT: I would prefer not to use ImageView, because I would like to change the image in specific locations, and using bitmap seemed to be the easiest way to accomplish that, via x and y coordinates.

Comment: android.widget.ImageView?

Comment: @krislarson I would prefer not to use ImageView, because I would like to change the image in specific locations, and using bitmap seemed to be the easiest way to accomplish that, via x and y coordinates.  The question has been updated to reflect this clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your custom view needs to override the `onMeasure` method and properly set the measured width and height so that the parent views (in this case the `ScrollView`) can know how much space to allocate for the child.

Comment: Thanks!  This was exactly what I was looking for.